# Git diff does not work with Windows absolute path

Tags: node.js, windows, git, cygwin

I am trying to check if a file has been modified(programically in Node) with `git diff --quiet` and then use the exit status code.

Working in Windows 7, I have no issues when it is in my cygwin shell. The exit status code is correct:

```
$ git diff --quiet /cygdrive/c/git/foo/bar/Home.js
$ !ech
echo $?
1
```

---

But when I use the windows full path in the Cygwin shell, I falsely get exit 0 status:

```
$ git diff --quiet "C:\\git\\foo\\bar\\Home.js"
$ echo $?
0
```

Why is this and how can I use the absolute windows path and get the correct exit status code?

**UPDATE** I found that git diff does not work at all/shows nothing when using windows absolute path. How do I use git diff with Windows absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cygpath` to convert the Windows path before feeding it to git.

Comment: Any reason you can't run `cygpath` in your script?

Comment: Other users who will be using the script will not have cygwin

Comment: How are they going to run the script then?  Is git the Cygwin git?  And if not, how does Cygwin even come into this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> I found that git diff does not work at all/shows nothing when using windows absolute path. How do I use git diff with Windows absolute path?

By using Git 2.20 (Q4 2018): it turned out that, under certain circumstances, "`git diff D:/a/b/c D:/a/b/d`" on Windows would strip initial parts from the paths because they
were not recognized as absolute, which has been corrected.

See [commit ffd04e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffd04e92e2c512cbbcb99526b064af302b443cb2) (19 Oct 2018) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 99499e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99499e222e8fc5b94db1fab386bd283059eb6771), 30 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `diff`: don't attempt to strip prefix from absolute Windows paths
>
> `git diff` can be invoked with absolute paths.
>   Typically, this triggers the `--no-index` case. Then the absolute paths remain in the file names that are printed in the output.
>
> There is one peculiarity, though: When the command is invoked from a a sub-directory in a repository, then it is attempted to strip the sub-directory from the beginning of relative paths.
>   Yet, to detect a relative path the code just checks for an initial forward slash.
>   This mistakes a Windows style path like "`D:/base`" as a relative path
>   and the output looks like this, for example:
>
> ```
> D:\dir\test\one>git -P diff --numstat D:\dir\base D:\dir\diff
> 1       1       ir/{base => diff}/1.txt
> ```
>
> where the correct output should be:
>
> ```
> D:\dir\test\one>git -P diff --numstat D:\dir\base D:\dir\diff
> 1       1       D:/dir/{base => diff}/1.txt
> ```
>
> If the sub-directory where '`git diff`' is invoked is sufficiently deep that the prefix becomes longer than the path to be printed, then the subsequent code accesses the path out of bounds.
>
> Use `is_absolute_path()` to detect Windows style absolute paths.